# RxAndroid http request in background using retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android

To better understand RxAndroid I found [this Repo](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples) which is full of useful examples using RxAndroid, especially in combination with Retrofit.

So if I look at [this](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/morihacky/android/rxjava/fragments/RetrofitFragment.java) part of the repo, I can make an http call by clicking an button which seems to be running in the background right?

What if I have this app which needs to show an activity/fragment and at the same time do some http call on the background and show the data if there is any received?

So for instance I have this fragment with onStart

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    pomagistoService
            .getAgenda()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())    // <- run in background right?
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Appointment>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() { }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) { }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Appointment> appointments) {
                    // show data in ListView
                }
            });
}
```

If I start this fragment a ListView instantaneously contains the data which is received by the http call.

Now the question/wondering I have is:
Does this http call run in the background?

I am asking this because of the data which is there immediately when the fragment appears, so I can't really observe it.

Comment: yes  the http call run in the background

Comment: @AmitShekhar oke, so let's say the http call takes 5seconds, it won't take 5seconds for the fragment to appear? The fragment just appears (without data)?

Comment: you should update the fragment listview from the onNext()

Comment: @AmitShekhar yeah yeah I know, am doing that! But because of the call is so fast the data is there before the fragment even had the change to show ;-p

Answer (score 0):

Usually, for network request you should use not `Schedulers.newThread()`, but `Schedulers.io()`. Also, to get some delay before request is executed and get a chance to see fragment without data try to use `.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` to make 5 seconds delay before call.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` then you're telling RxJava to do its job in background (another thread).
`Schedulers.io()` is usaually used for I/O operations like networking, you can use `Schedulers.computation()` for long processing operations running locally.

and by using `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` you're telling that you want to recieve the final result in the main thread so you can show it or handle ui events.

some common error is the confusion when using `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()`, so to make it easy for you .. you're always want to observe results on main thread to reflect it in UI otherwise use what fit your case.